# How to create more children on Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create more children on the Firebase Realtime Database.
Desired effect (example): [[image: Firebase Realtime Database1]

What I have:

```
 MyButton(
  label: "Create Ride",
  onTap: () {
    ref
        .child('Database')
        .push()
        .child('Title')
        .set(_titleController.text)//the Title Controller is just the 
                                           //data you type in
        .asStream();
    _titleController.clear();
  }),
```

I can't find a sample anywhere and I don't know how to write it so that there's more than just a title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write multiple values under the new child, you can do:

```
ref
    .child('Database')
    .push()
    .set({
      'Title': _titleController.text,
      'land': 'Germany',
      'stadt': 'Berlin'
    })
```

Also see the example in the Firebase documentation on [writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#write_data).